# Find the date difference in php

Tags: php

I want to know what's the way to find the difference of two date. I get the startDate and endDate from a form. Now I want to find the difference of current date and startDate or endDate.

```
echo $startDate = $startYear.'-'.$startMonth.'-'.$startDay.'<br>';
echo $endDate = $endYear.'-'.$endMonth.'-'.$endDay;
$_SESSION['startDate'] = $startDate;
$_SESSION['endDate'] = $endDate;
$_SESSION['team'] = $team;
header('location:test.php');
```

test.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
    echo $startDate = $_SESSION['startDate'];
    $date2=date_create(date('Y/m/d'));
    $diff=date_diff($startDate,$date2);
    echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: That was 7 years ago, the version of php is too old.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$date1=strtotime("2016-07-02");
$date2=strtotime(date('Y/m/d'));
$diff = $date2 - $date1;
echo ($diff / (60 * 60 * 24)) . ' days';
```